# My form returns null value in the submit Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I am working on a personal project with Angular. I am occupying the forms, but when I submit my form using the submit button, the value it has is null.
*This is the HTML code*

```
<form [formGroup]="checkoutform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Nro en Pokedex</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ingrese ID Pokemon"
    class="input"
    formControlName="pokeid">
</mat-form-field>
<div *ngIf="checkoutform.get('pokeid').errors && checkoutform.get('pokeid').dirty">
    <p class="pp" *ngIf="checkoutform.get('pokeid').hasError('required')">Este campo es obliatorio</p>
    <p class="pp" *ngIf="checkoutform.get('pokeid').hasError('pattern')">Solo numeros</p>
</div>
<div class="containerButton">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
    class="button"
    [disabled]="checkoutform.invalid"
    type="submit"
    >Buscar Pokemon</button>
</div>
```

*This is the TS code:*

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PokeServiceService} from './../../../core/services/poke-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-search',
  templateUrl: './bar-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-search.component.scss']
})
export class BarSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  checkoutform;
  constructor(
    private formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private pokeservice: PokeServiceService
  ) {
    this.buildForm();
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  private buildForm() {
    this.checkoutform = this.formbuilder.group({
      pokeid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]],
    });
  }
  get pokeidField() {
    return this.checkoutform.get('pokeid');
  }
  onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.checkoutform.reset();
    if (this.checkoutform.valid) {
      var poked = this.checkoutform.value;
      this.pokeservice.getPokebyID(poked)
      .subscribe((newPoke) => {
        console.log(newPoke);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(this.checkoutform.value);
      console.log(poked.pokeid);
      console.log('error');
    }
    }
  }
```

*In the TS Code, implement some console.log to see the value of each variable, but they all return null to me*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the reset form call . it will set the form control pokeid to null.

you should change the code as below.

```
onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.checkoutform.valid) {
      var poked = this.checkoutform.value;
      this.pokeservice.getPokebyID(poked).subscribe(newPoke => {
        console.log(newPoke);
        this.checkoutform.reset();
      });
    } else {
      console.log(this.checkoutform.value);
      console.log(poked.pokeid);
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
}
```

you can reset the form in the api calls subscription block.

Comment: Thanks bro! You are the best! ;D greetings from Chile 